# Wordpress combining get_posts and category_name functions on custom post type and ACF

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I was trying to get some posts from a Custom Post Type "dish" with a value of ACF as the price. I am trying to show the name of the dishes with the price and came up with this code. I want to know if the loop part in this code is considered good practice?

```
<div id="main-content">
    <div class="container-lg overflow-hidden">
        <div class="row gx-5 d-flex flex-wrap">
            <?php 
            $categories = get_categories();
            foreach ($categories as $category){
                $categoryName = $category->name; // look into the object named $category and then look into the variable named "name"
                if ($categoryName != "Uncategorized"){
                    ?>
                        <div class="p-4 col-6">
                            <div>
                                <h3><?php echo $categoryName;?></h3>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            $args = array(
                                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                'post_type' => "dish",
                                'category_name' => $categoryName
                            );
                            $dishes = get_posts($args);
                            foreach ($dishes as $dish){
                                ?>
                                <div>
                                    <span><?php echo $dish->post_title; ?></span>
                                    <span class="float-end"><?php echo the_field('price', $dish); ?></span>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I didn't use the `have_posts()` loop as I thought all post would be called for each category. So I am not sure now if the code I used is a good practice on the archive page. The other way I saw was to custom query for each category. But again I wasn't sure if Custom query inside a loop would be a good idea in case there were thousands of post. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**
Yes it's fine. I'd use the same approach every time. Avoid writing your own custom sql query whenever you can. The combination of `get_posts` and `category_name` works just fine.

---

Not sure if this a typo or not, but i'd also replace:

```php
<span class="float-end"><?php echo the_field('price', $dish); ?></span>
```

with

```php
<span class="float-end"><?php echo the_field('price', $dish->ID); ?></span>
```

Comment: Sweet thank you. Trying WordPress with php is a whole different thing apparently in comparison to web builders.